# Edit Google Sheets from Python, see changes on browser

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to edit a Google Sheets file via python. I am working with the Google APIs but all of them make changes "on the back end" (like openpyxl). I want to see the changes on the browser. To me, it's like running selenium headless vs. "normal".

I tried this code from GoogleAPIclient:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
         'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
```

and this code from gspread

```
import gspread
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
         'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds) #from another website
sheet = client.open(file_id) #from another website
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the same changes through the GUI (clicking buttons etc.)? Or do you want to see the changes you're doing in the API reflected in the doc as they are made?

Comment: What is the question?